# Adding a COM reference for UWP application

Tags: uwp

Am currently trying to utilize a 3rd party SDK which requires me to add it as a COM reference, since the app is currently built on Universal Windows PLatform, I cannot do so.

Is there any way where this can be done ?
Can I create a new app just to integrate this SDK and then establish a communication between this new app and the UWP app ?

Comment: If the app depends on an external COM provider, then the app can't be UWP.  And really, why do you care about UWP?

Comment: @TimRoberts This was a stop gap solution done early on so we can support both tablets and windows desktops, now it has become a PITA solution. So looking for options, if it means that writing a new app and then communicating with UWP somehow am open to that also.